# wget does not work on busybox (docker container): TLS handshake failure

Tags: docker, ssl, wget, tls1.2, busybox

Foreword: I'm new to busybox.

Issue: wget fails to download files, such as https://www.netfilter.org/projects/iptables/files/iptables-1.8.9.tar.xz, while other transfers work fine (e.g. wget https://github.com/docker-library/busybox/archive/master.zip).

```
rofz@iMac: ~ % docker run -it busybox  
/ # wget --version
wget: unrecognized option '--version'
BusyBox v1.36.1 (2023-07-17 18:29:09 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: wget [-cqS] [--spider] [-O FILE] [-o LOGFILE] [--header STR]
    [--post-data STR | --post-file FILE] [-Y on/off]
    [--no-check-certificate] [-P DIR] [-U AGENT] [-T SEC] URL...

Retrieve files via HTTP or FTP

    --spider    Only check URL existence: $? is 0 if exists
    --header STR    Add STR (of form 'header: value') to headers
    --post-data STR Send STR using POST method
    --post-file FILE    Send FILE using POST method
    --no-check-certificate  Don't validate the server's certificate
    -c      Continue retrieval of aborted transfer
    -q      Quiet
    -P DIR      Save to DIR (default .)
    -S          Show server response
    -T SEC      Network read timeout is SEC seconds
    -O FILE     Save to FILE ('-' for stdout)
    -o LOGFILE  Log messages to FILE
    -U STR      Use STR for User-Agent header
    -Y on/off   Use proxy
/ # wget https://github.com/docker-library/busybox/archive/master.zip
Connecting to github.com (192.30.255.113:443)
wget: note: TLS certificate validation not implemented
Connecting to codeload.github.com (140.82.112.10:443)
saving to 'master.zip'
master.zip           100% |*****************************************************************************************************| 34890  0:00:00 ETA
'master.zip' saved
/ # wget https://www.netfilter.org/projects/iptables/files/iptables-1.8.9.tar.xz
Connecting to www.netfilter.org (92.243.18.11:443)
wget: note: TLS certificate validation not implemented
wget: TLS error from peer (alert code 40): handshake failure
wget: error getting response: Connection reset by peer
/ #
```

Any ideas?

Note: I understand and I don't really care about TLS certificate validation (saw the issues raised in docker-library/busybox repo). The target issue here is the handshake failure for a specific URL/website.

Comment: Add in `wget` option `--no-check-certificate`

Comment: @RomeoNinov: A server issued TLS alert which happens here has nothing to do with client site certificate validation. Apart from that this uses the busybox builtin TLS implementation which does not validate certificates anyway (as the output clearly says). So the option would not help.

Comment: Looks for me like a bug with sec256p1 curve implementation in busybox native TLS. Testing against `openssl s_server` produces the same problem and shows the error `EC_POINT_set_affine_coordinates:point is not on curve`. Forcing s_server to use X25519 instead successfully results in ECDHE key exchange.

Comment: There is likely not much you can do except also install openssl on the image. busybox wget will use this if installed instead of its own tiny TLS stack and then it should work.

Comment: Thanks @steffen-ullrich, I was under the impression that there was something wrong indeed with busybox's TLS support. This reference might be a good indication of the underlying issue: https://github.com/docker-library/busybox/issues/162
Agreed, not much to do here.